# Red glowing borders in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am currently building a website for a client, and am experiencing an issue in IE, the borders are all red. The website is at http://commercialcreditchecks.com and anywhere there is a boxshadow the boxshadow is red instead of the assigned blue, additionally the linked logo image has a red border, even though borders are set to none. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting the border:none; on the img-tag instead of the A-tag?

Comment: Yes I have, however I haven't done that since I noticed it was red in IE, let me try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in your styling. On class name `.cta` you have the following set:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(Color=#333,Strength=15); MARGIN: 0px auto
```

Within that is the part `Color=#333`

Maybe try:

```
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(Color=Gray,Strength=10); MARGIN: 0px auto
```

or try `Silver` as it looks closer to Gray20 (#333333)

[MSDN Doc Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532995%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will help

Comment: Forgive me if I am misunderstanding, but `#333` is a dark grey isn't it? How are the colors red. Additionally, there isn't an assigned boxshadow on the logo yet it is still red as well.

Comment: can't accept an answer for 5 mins, but I will when I can, thanks again! And when are they just going to scrap IE? :p

Comment: Lol, I wish! IE is just horrible, but government and medical still "trust" it (morons) thus it wont go anywhere for a `loooooooooong` time. I love how IE9 claimed it would be fully HTML5 and CSS3 ... What happened to that? ... Will IE10?

Comment: Too true, IE needs to be scraped from a development aspect, but so long as it comes standard on pcs it isn't going anywhere.

Comment: @HTMLDeveloper what do you mean? This worked just fine, however I just changed it to `color=#333333`

Comment: "@HTMLDeveloper what do you mean? This worked just fine, however I just changed it to color=#333333" Test in all relevant versions of IE (7-10). #333333 i tested in IE8 and got red border

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css. For IE use

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";
    zoom: 1;
```

For chrome, safari browsers use

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #0066FF;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #0066FF;
```